# Importbuddy Internal 500 Server Error Step 3

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am attempting to duplicate a website onto a separate domain for testing purposes.
However when I run importbuddy.php all is well until I reach the 3rd step. The 3rd step involves entering your Database details. I enter the details and click test, everything comes up with 'pass' and i click 'next step'....

After waiting for 5 - 10 mins the page throws up a 500 Internal Server Error. I have tried increasing memory limit and max execution time but to no avail.

I tried backing up another site and moving it onto the said domain above and it worked flawlessly.

Below is the log:

> Importing database content with ImportBuddy v4.2.15.3 (downloaded 2014-04-16T07:38:49+00:00)... Powered by BackupBuddy.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    0.97    details Maximum PHP execution time was not modified
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    0.97    details Reported PHP execution time - Configured: 600; Original: 7200; Current: 7200
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    0.97    details Reported PHP memory limits - Configured: 512M; Original: 512M; Current: 512M
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    0.97    message Migrating `.htaccess.bb_temp` file...
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    0.97    message Checking `.htaccess.bb_temp` file.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    0.97    message URL directory has changed. Updating from `` to `/mariesa`.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    0.97    details .htaccess ^index/.php$ detected. Leaving as is.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    0.97    message Migrated `.htaccess.bb_temp` file. It will be renamed back to `.htaccess` on the final step.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    0.97    message Verifying database connection and settings...
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    0.97    message Database connection and settings verified. Connected to database `inbc_marie`.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    0.97    details Determining SQL file location...
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    0.97    details Looking for SQL file at `backupbuddy_dat.php/db_1.sql`.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    0.97    details Looking for SQL file at `/usr/www/users/inbccbtvgs/mariesa/wp-content/uploads/temp_vnb9u43goi/db.sql`.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    0.97    details Looking for SQL file at `/usr/www/users/inbccbtvgs/mariesa/db.sql`.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    0.97    details Looking for SQL file at `/usr/www/users/inbccbtvgs/mariesa/wp-content/uploads/backupbuddy_temp/vnb9u43goi/db_1.sql`.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    0.97    details Found SQL file as `/usr/www/users/inbccbtvgs/mariesa/wp-content/uploads/backupbuddy_temp/vnb9u43goi/db_1.sql`.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    1.03    details Compatibility mysqldump (if applicable) max rows per select set to 2000.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    1.04    details Database host for dumping: `dedi498.jnb1.host-h.net`
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    1.04    details Loading mysqldump library.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    1.04    details Mysql server default directories: `/usr/bin/,/usr/bin/mysql/,/usr/local/bin/`
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    1.04    details mysqlbuddy: Force method of `0` passed.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    1.04    message mysqlbuddy: Method not forced. About to detect directory and available methods.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    1.04    details mysqlbuddy: Attempting to calculate exact mysql directory.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    1.04    details mysqlbuddy: Mysql reported its directory. Reported: `/usr`; Adding binary location to beginning of mysql directory list: `/usr/bin/`
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    1.04    details mysqldump test: Testing available mysql database dump methods.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    1.04    details mysqldump test: exec() function exists. Testing running mysqldump via exec().
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    1.04    details mysqldump test running next.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    1.04    details exec_dir not detected. Proceeding normally.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.01    1.04    details exec() command `PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/:/usr/local/bin/:usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin/:/usr/sbin/:/sbin/:/usr/:/bin/; /usr/bin/mysqldump --version  2>&1` (with path definition).
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.02    1.05    details exec() command output: `mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu (i686)`; Exit code: `0`; Exit code description: `Command completed & returned normally.`
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.02    1.05    details mysqldump test: Command appears to be accessible and returns expected response.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.02    1.05    message mysqlbuddy: Detected database dump methods: `commandline,php`.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.02    1.05    details If applicable, breaking up with max execution time `30` seconds.
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.02    1.05    message Restoring database dump. This may take a moment...
>
> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am   0.02    1.05    error   Error #9014: Database import halted to prevent overwriting existing WordPress data. The database already contains a WordPress installation with this prefix `ms_` (21 tables). Restore has been stopped to prevent overwriting existing data.

If any more information is required please ask.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> Apr 16, 2014 10:12:51 am 0.02 1.05 error Error #9014: Database import
>   halted to prevent overwriting existing WordPress data. The database
>   already contains a WordPress installation with this prefix ms_ (21
>   tables). Restore has been stopped to prevent overwriting existing
>   data.

The table already exists and its breaking here?

Comment: Yeah i thought the same at first, however I've deleted the database, created a new one and followed the same process but it still throws up the 500 server error :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when restoring a BackupBuddy backup with importbuddy.php
It turned out that some files in the root directory that were unpacked from the backup caused the internal 500 Server Error [screenshot of problematic files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQxAk.png)

.htacces.bb_temp /.user.ini /.maintenance etc.
I wonder where these came from, since the original site worked fine.

So the steps to fix this error are:

1. Extract all files with importbuddy as you normally would
2. Connect to your FTP or File Manager from the Hosting Control Panel (Plesk, Nodeworx, etc) and delete those problematic files (you can always download a backup before).
3. Only now should you continue with the database installation
4. Done, everything works, no need to reupload those files. WP seems to create a new .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

As @Matt has noted table are already created might be because first the process was stopped due to some error.

Just try to empty the whole database from phpmyadmin then try again. And you might be done. or print errors here if anything else happen.

Comment: As stated below, I have tried what you are suggesting but the result unfortunately didn't change. I've had a look at the error logs on the server but it doesn't mention anything there that is of importance.

Comment: well it should work as documented here:  http://ithemes.com/codex/page/BackupBuddy:_Error_Codes#9014

Comment: Indeed, but for some odd reason it doesn't think the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution.

I used the PHP compatibility mode and did the database import in smaller chunks. Everything working perfectly now.